# What is going wrong with my split() function?

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```py
player2023[['First Name', 'Last Name']] = player2023.Player.str.split(n=2, expand=True)
```

I was told to do that, opposed to the following code:

```py
player2023[['First Name', 'Last Name']] = player2023.Player.str.split(expand=True)
```

I keep getting the same error for both:

```py
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

The data sample of the `Player` attribute is `John Smith`

Comment: is `player2023` a dataframe?

Comment: @ScottC Yes it is

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure the column `Player` has at least two words, and assuming the last word is what you want in the last name column, something like this will do the job:

```py
import panda as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Player': 'John Doe'},
    {'Player': 'Jane Doe Too'}
])

df[['First', 'Last']] = df.Player.str.rsplit(n=1, expand=True)
```

Which leaves `df` like:

```py
         Player     First Last
0      John Doe      John  Doe
1  Jane Joe Too  Jane Doe  Too
```